# AndroidBootstrap could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt

How to solve it when I import eclipse project into my android studio

Image to understand issue

[image]

Comment: Please try to describe question description with image

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1:**
Import Eclipse Project to Android Studio:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project.
   Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, click Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.).
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.
4. Select the destination folder and click Next.
5. Select the import options and click Finish.
6. The import process prompts you to migrate any library and project dependencies to Android Studio, and add the dependency declarations to the build.gradle file.

**For detail description try this link**

> https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrating_from_eclipse

**Edit2:**

Well, there might be another way of solving this problem, but I ended up removing the line in the `project.properties` file that was making reference to the **Android Bootstrap library**.